# Why unwanted information show in Wordpress widget?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I am working with Wordpress widget. I have registered sidebar in functions.php. I have registered two sidebars. Second one is working fine but with first widget  **additional 1** ( *numeric number one*) is coming with it's text  like that...

[image]

This is the code that I write in functions. php

```
 register_sidebar([
    'name'           =>  __('Left Sidebar Top', 'ajie'),
    'description'    =>  __('You can set left sidebar here', 'ajie'),
    'id'             =>  'image-sidebar',
    'before_widget'  => '',
    'after_widget'   => '',
    'before_title'   => '',
    'after_title'    => '',
]);
```

I have tried to solve it in deffernt ways but somewhat don't work well. Any kinds of help will be appreciate able.

Comment: Post your code as well

Comment: I think you are echoing dynamic_sidebar

Comment: Oh Amit that's right. it is for echoing the sidebar. However,  thank you for your kind co-operation.